# Is there a way to download the image to the gallery by receiving the URL which I uploaded to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I stored some url to the Cloud Firestore and I successfully displayed those images to my app but the question is "can I download the image using that url ?" 
If possible please help me

I watched alot of tutorials but I cant find any solution, I dont know even its possible, please describe your answer.

```
 StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;
 List<DocumentSnapshot> wallpapersList;
 final CollectionReference collectionReference =
     Firestore.instance.collection('wallpapers');

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
     setState(() {<br>
       wallpapersList = datasnapshot.documents;
     });
   });
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   subscription?.cancel();
   super.dispose();
 }


body: wallpapersList != null
         ? new StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
             crossAxisCount: 4,
             itemCount: wallpapersList.length,
             itemBuilder: (context, i) {
               String imgPath = wallpapersList[i].data['url'];

               return new Material(
                 elevation: 8.0,
                 borderRadius:
                     new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(8.0)),
                 child: ClipRRect(
                   borderRadius:
                       new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(8.0)),
                   child: new InkWell(
                     onTap: () {
                       Navigator.push(
                           context,
                           new MaterialPageRoute(
                               builder: (context) =>
                                   new FullScreenImagePage(imgPath)));
                     },
                     child: new Hero(
                       tag: imgPath,
                       child: new FadeInImage(
                         fit: BoxFit.cover,
                         image: new NetworkImage(
                           imgPath,
                         ),
                         placeholder: new AssetImage(
                           "images/robot.png",
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               );
             },
             staggeredTileBuilder: (i) =>
                 new StaggeredTile.count(2, i.isEven ? 2 : 3),
             mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
             crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
           )
         : new Center(
             child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
           ),);
 }
} 
**bold** SCREEN SHOT
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/41YS2.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [Image Picker Saver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_saver) or [Network to File Image](https://pub.dev/packages/network_to_file_image)? These packages were created especially for downloading images by URL.

I've tried [Image Downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader) and it's working:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:image_downloader/image_downloader.dart';

    class FullScreenImagePage extends StatefulWidget {
      final String imgPath;
      FullScreenImagePage(this.imgPath);
      @override
      _FullScreenImagePageState createState() => _FullScreenImagePageState();
    }

    class _FullScreenImagePageState extends State<FullScreenImagePage> {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(widget.imgPath),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Container()),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => _onImageSaveButtonPressed(widget.imgPath),
              child: Text("Press me"))
        ]));
      }

      void _onImageSaveButtonPressed(String url) async {
        await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url,
            destination: AndroidDestinationType.directoryPictures);
      }
    }
```

Don't forget to add the following to AndroidManifest for Android

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Yeah but I dont know how to get the http, can you please help me with the above code ? Thanks

Comment: Could you describe more details for me? Do you want to download image instead of open it?

Comment: I opened the image but i don't know how to download it, I just need to know if i click a button the image should save in the gallery i tried watching alot of tutorial but i can't do it. I'm new for programming , can you please do that?Thanks for your time

Comment: class FullScreenImagePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imgPath;
  FullScreenImagePage(this.imgPath);

  @override
  _FullScreenImagePageState createState() => _FullScreenImagePageState();
}

class _FullScreenImagePageState extends State<FullScreenImagePage> {
  final LinearGradient backgroundColor = new LinearGradient(
    colors: [Color(0x10000000), Color(0x30000000)],
    begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
  );  RaisedButton(onpressed(){} "If I click the raised button it should download"